# Can you use a colon for loop with multidimensional arrays?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

As you probably know you can use a colon for loop to shorten code like this:

```
int testarray[] = {3, 4, 5};

for (int i : testarray) {

   System.out.println(i);

}
```

Is it possible to do this with multi-multidimensional array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need a nested `for-loop`. First iterate over the arrays in `testarray`, then in the `inner-for` iterate over the `int` elements.

```
int testarray[][] = {{3, 4}, {5,6}};
for (int[] arr : testarray) {
    for (int i : arr) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to acheive what you wanted...

```
int testarray[][] = {{1,2,4},{3, 4, 5}};
for(int j=0; j < testarray.length; j++)
{
    for (int i : testarray[j]) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This is another way of doing it.

```
for(int[] subArray: testarray)
{
     for (int i : subArray) {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
}
```